# NPE when iterating over Hibernate PersistentSet

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm seeing a sporadic NullPointerException in my logs when iterating over a PersistentSet. I can't seem to reproduce the problem, I was hoping someone could shed some light on the stacktrace based of a code fragment.

Relevant stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException


org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getLoadedCollectionOwnerOrNull(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:745)

org.hibernate.event.spi.AbstractCollectionEvent.getLoadedOwnerOrNull(AbstractCollectionEvent.java:75)

org.hibernate.event.spi.InitializeCollectionEvent.<init>(InitializeCollectionEvent.java:36)

org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1895)

org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:555)

org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)

org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:551)

org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:140)

org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:180)

eu.mycompany.soft.html.FooForm.doStuff(thisForm.java:1426)
[...]
```

Triggering code:

```
Foo foo = session.load(Foo.class, id);
List<Foo> childFooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
//Using .addAll() also triggers the error
if (foo != null && foo.getChildFooSet() != null) {
    for(Foo childFoo :foo.getChildFooSet()) {
        childFooList.add(childFoo);
    }
}
```

Foo Class:

```
public class Foo extends IdObject {
    
    [...]
    // Relevant attributes:
    // a foo belongs either to a bar
    // or another parent foo (in the latter case indirectly to a
    // bar)
    private Bar bar = null;
    private Foo parentFoo = null;

    protected Set<Foo> fooSet = new HashSet<ExecutedProtocol>();
    
    [...]
```

Foo Class' Hibernate Mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
        
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="eu.mycompany.soft.to.Foo" table="foo">
    <id name="id" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="bar" column="barID"/>
    <many-to-one name="parentFoo" column="parentFooId"/>
    <set name="childFooSet" inverse="true" order-by="dateTime">
      <key column="parentFooId"/>
      <one-to-many class="eu.mycompany.soft.to.Foo"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I'm suspecting something is going wrong with the Foo Class' identity (it uses default equals()/hashCode()), but I can't reproduce the error to confirm it.

Comment: with default hashCode/equals you mean that you didn't implement them?

Comment: Yes, did not override them

Comment: Are you sure that the stacktrace is complete? All I could find is implemented null-safe. What is the code in `thisForm.java:1426` exactly?

Comment: The stacktrace is not complete (hence the [...]) but the last part of the call stack is pretty irrelevant. thisForm.java:1426 corresponds to this line of code: `for(Foo childFoo :foo.getChildFooSet())`

Comment: How do you get `foo`? What is the mapping?

Comment: I knew I forgot something, I'll add an abbreviated version of the mapping

Comment: Would in theory look ok. Have you done debugging to check what is null at `StatefulPersistenceContext.getLoadedCollectionOwnerOrNull`? The only thing that would come to my mind is that you are not in a transaction, but that would usually cause a different exception